# Excel MaxIF and Vlookup Combo

Tags: excel, formula, multiple-columns, vlookup

Trying to find a formula for the following:

[image: ExampleImage]

Given 3 columns, for each change in Column1, find the max value in column 3, and return the corresponding value in column2.  So for ID 1 it would return Loc6, because 20 is the highest total associated with ID 1.  For ID 2 it would return Loc2, etc.

Comment: Are you thinking this formula would exist in Column4?

Comment: the reason you cannot get a vlookup to work is that you actally require an index/match instead.

Comment: Yes, ideally column 4 is where the formula would go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the unique ID to look for somewhere (in this example I put them in column E starting in row 2) and then for the MaxLoc, I used this formula in cell F2 and copied down:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$10=E2)*$C$2:$C$10,)),INDEX(($A$2:$A$10=E2)*$C$2:$C$10,),0))
```

[image]